# Passport Components not showing up in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, node.js, laravel-5

I followed this [tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport) and I'm on "Passport's default Vue frontend". The problem now is the Vue Components not showing up in Laravel 5.4.
The resources/js/app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');
Vue.component(
    'passport-clients',
    require('./components/passport/Clients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-authorized-clients',
    require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-personal-access-tokens',
    require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue')
);
window.Vue = require('vue');


Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

The resources/views/home.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    You are logged inn!
                    <passport-clients></passport-clients>
                    <passport-authorized-clients></passport-authorized-clients>
                    <passport-personal-access-tokens></passport-personal-access-tokens>

                    <example></example>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I run "npm run dev" in cmd but I cannot see component in my views. I cannot see example component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was very spoiled.
I should be  write components of the lines in the file at the end of  app.js file. After  window.vue...